# Need to write regex for top-level web address which includes letters, numbers, underscores as well as periods, dashes, and a plus sign

Tags: python, regex

The `check_web_address` function checks if the text passed qualifies as a top-level web address, meaning that it contains alphanumeric characters (which includes letters, numbers, and underscores), as well as periods, dashes, and a plus sign, followed by a period and a character-only top-level domain such as ".com", ".info", ".edu", etc. Fill in the regular expression to do that, using escape characters, wildcards, repetition qualifiers, beginning and end-of-line characters, and character classes.

```
import re

def check_web_address(text):
  pattern = ___
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_web_address("gmail.com")) # True
print(check_web_address("www@google")) # False
print(check_web_address("www.Coursera.org")) # True
print(check_web_address("web-address.com/homepage")) # False
print(check_web_address("My_Favorite-Blog.US")) # True
```

I have tried with this pattern but all sample input came true:

```
pattern = '[^/@][A-Za-z._-]*$'
```

What will be exact pattern to cover all above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have got this way to cover all above scenarios with below code,

```
import re
def check_web_address(text):
  pattern = r'^[A-Za-z._-][^/@]*$'
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_web_address("gmail.com")) # True
print(check_web_address("www@google")) # False
print(check_web_address("www.Coursera.org")) # True
print(check_web_address("web-address.com/homepage")) # False
print(check_web_address("My_Favorite-Blog.US")) # True
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is wrong based on problem requirements! Please check my answer and explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562952/6296708

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine

```
  pattern = r"^\w.*\.[a-zA-Z]*$"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is wrong based on problem requirements! `.*` is equal to any characters including the whitespace, and all other symbols. Please check my answer and explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562952/6296708

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that I used to accomplish this was:

```
pattern = "^[\w]*[\.\-\+][^/@]*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

**I did it this way**

```
import re
def check_web_address(text):
  pattern = r'^[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]*[.][A-Za-z]*$'
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_web_address("gmail.com")) # True
print(check_web_address("www@google")) # False
print(check_web_address("www.Coursera.org")) # True
print(check_web_address("web-address.com/homepage")) # False
print(check_web_address("My_Favorite-Blog.US")) # True
```

**^** *start*

**[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]*** *repetition qualifiers of alphanumeric characters (which includes letters, numbers, and underscores), as well as periods, dashes, and a plus sign*

**[.]** *followed by a period*

**[A-Za-z]*** *a character-only top-level domain such as ".com", ".info", ".edu", etc*

**$** *End*

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-+_.@]*\.+[^@/]*$"
```

This code should work fine it takes on all possible cases including two interesting ones which usual codes don't work:

print(check_web_address("scobbydo101@gmail.com")) #True
print(check_web_address("scobbydo101@gmail.@com")) #False

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this pattern:

`pattern = "\.[a-zA-Z]+$"`

This should work too. It checks if result contains dots followed by one or more occurence of upper of lower case alphabets at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r"^[\w|\.\-\_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_web_address(text):
  pattern = r'^[\w\-+.]+\.[a-zA-z]+$'
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_web_address("gmail.com")) # True  
print(check_web_address("www@google")) # False.  
print(check_web_address("www.Coursera.org")) # True
print(check_web_address("web-address.com/homepage")) # False.    
print(check_web_address("My_Favorite-Blog.US")) # True
```

**Explanations**

1. `^[\w\-+.]+` => beginning of the expression should start with word,+,- .
   eg: www.Coursera or www.89+- so on and can at-least have one character matching so '+' at the end
2. `\.` => simple to catch middle section of pattern www.somedomain.
3. `[a-zA-z]+$` => matchs .in or .IN  simple pattern expression because domain are simple without any special characters

Hopes it helps :) Happy Stacking

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_web_address(text):
  pattern = r'\.[comeduorginfoUSnetintmilgov]*$'
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_web_address('gmail.com')) # True
print(check_web_address('www.google')) # False
print(check_web_address('www.Coursera.org')) # True
print(check_web_address('web-address.com/homepage')) # False
print(check_web_address('My_Favorite-Blog.US')) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most accurate:
`pattern = r"^[\w.+-]*\.[a-zA-Z]*$"`

Answer (score 0):

We should pay attention to the requirements of our problem! it asked for 4 criteria:

- contains alphanumeric characters (which includes **letters**, **numbers**, and **underscores**), as well as **periods**, **dashes**, and a **plus sign** (`[\w.+-]+?`)
- followed by a **period** (`\.`) and
- a **character-only** top-level domain such as ".com", ".info", ".edu", etc (`[a-zA-Z]+?`)
- ..., **beginning** and **end-of-line** characters,... (`r"^...$"`)

Therefore, it should be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

def check_web_address(text):
    pattern = r"^[\w.+-]+?\.[a-zA-Z]+?$"
    result = re.search(pattern, text)
    return bool(result)


print(1, "Should be 'True':", check_web_address("gmail.com"))  # True
print(2, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("www@google"))  # False
print(3, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("www.Coursera.org"))  # True
print(4, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("web-address.com/homepage"))  # False
print(5, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("My_Favorite-Blog.US"))  # True
print(6, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address(" www.test6.com"))  # False
print(7, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("123.test7.com"))  # True
print(8, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("123.test8.123"))  # False
print(9, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("ww!.test9.net"))  # False
print(10, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("w w.test10.net"))  # False
print(11, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("w+w.test11.net"))  # True
print(12, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("w-w.test12.net"))  # True
print(13, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("pass.under.test13.net"))  # True
print(14, "Should be 'True':",  check_web_address("Just-For.You+mE.TesT+14+.net"))  # True
print(15, "Should be 'False':",  check_web_address("www.test15.net."))  # False
```

**You may ask**: Why did you use repeating character `?` after repeating character `+`?

I did that to make `+` [non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy)! Of course, you can also not use it too!

Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

### This Should Work fine:

```
pattern = r".*\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}.$"
```

### In One long sentence:

### Here we filter any number of character(.*) followed by a period(.) then check for 2 or 3 ending character capital or small ([A-Za-z]{1,3}.$)
Here:

`.*` : Accepts any Number of any character.

`\.` :  Backslash '' is escape character so it is only period('.')

`[A-Za-z]` : character class [A-Za-z] means Accepts capital and small Alphabets,

`{1,3}` : to limit above ([A-Za-z]) character between 1 & 3 (excluding 1 including 3)

`.` : usually it means any One single character but with {1,3} it accepts the provided number of character.

`$` : means the string should end with

### In One long sentence:

Here we filter any number of character(.*) followed by a period(.) then check for 2 or 3 ending character capital or small ([A-Za-z]{1,3}.$)

Comment: I don't think `.*` would be correct here as it's under-constrained and would include more characters allowed by the question.